# What is the need of making event variables in event handling C#?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I read about how to make event handlers, I found that all tutorials and articles used to make delegates and event variables. I didn't understand why do they use event variables as we can make event handlers using delegates only like this code:

```
namespace EventsTest
{     
    public class Counter
    {
        public delegate void ReachedEventHandler(object sender);
        public ReachedEventHandler fireEvent;
        // public event ReachedEventHandler fireevent;
        private int counter = 0;

        public void Add(int x, int toReach)
        {
            counter += x;
            if (counter == toReach && fireEvent != null)
               fireEvent(this);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Counter x = new Counter();
            x.fireEvent += new Counter.ReachedEventHandler(CounterReachedEventHandler);
            x.Add(1, 1);
        }

        private static void CounterReachedEventHandler(object sender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reached!");
        }
    }
}
```

This will work, so what is the need of making event variables?

Thanks!

Comment: For one, it's syntax sugar: less code and no fumbling around with explicit delegate definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event` keyword guarantees encapsulation: you won't be able to call or modify `fireEvent` outside of `Counter`. The only available operations outside are subscribing and unsubscribing (`+=` and `-=`).

A few notes on your code:

1. In general, you should use `EventHandler` delegate instead of defining your own equivalent (`ReachedEventHandler`) and `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` in case of custom `EventArgs`.
2. Your `ReachedEventHandler` does not follow standard convention for events. They should have two arguments (`object sender` and `TEventArgs args`, where `TEventArgs` is `EventArgs` or subclass) and return `void`.
3. Explicit `new Counter.ReachedEventHandler()` call is unnecessary too.

Comment: Exactly Athari, great answer.

Comment: @Athari Sorry, But what do you mean I will not be able to call or modify fireEvent outside of Counter?

Comment: Outside of Counter means code in methods and properties not belonging to Counter.

Comment: @Athari Ok, I got your point, but why new Counter.ReachedEventHandler() is unnecessary?

Comment: If you just write `x.fireEvent += CounterReachedEventHandler`, the compiler will call the constructor for you. The result will be the same. It's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of using an `event` over a `delegate` is that the compiler generated the add/remove pluming for you. For example if you've got:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FooEvent;
```

Then the compiler will automatically generate the `add` and `remove` methods for you. These methods will populate the underlying delegate, and will do so in a thread-safe manner, so that you don't have to worry about locking the underlying delegate.

In addition, any consumers of your class will only be able to add and remove handlers to the delegate, they won't be able to make a call against the delegate (i.e. they won't be able to raise the event). Only your class will be able to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that code won't be thread-safe without `event`? Delegates instances never change, new ones are always created, so it should always be safe to use them.

Comment: @Athari Immutability != thread-safety. `int` is immutable, and `i++` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @Athari - if two thread both read the existing delegate and then each create a new one with their delegate appended and then write back to the variable holding the delegate then there's a potential race condition whereby one of the appends won't be seen.

Comment: How does `event` guarantee that it doesn't happen?

Comment: The 'add' and 'remove' methods that are generated are threadsafe. They use to do a `lock(this)` on instance events, or `lock(typeof(classname))` on static events, but were changed in .NET 4 (I think) to use `Interlocked.CompareExchange`

Answer (score 2):

It is to stop somebody from writing code like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass(Counter counter) {
        // Myhahaha, your base belongs to me!
        counter.fireEvent = new ReachedEventHandler(reached); 
    }
    private void reached(object sender) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Which wipes out any other code that is also listening for the event, their event handlers will never be called.

An *event* is an **accessor** for a delegate object, it only permits += to add and -= to remove an event handler.  With the further restriction that you can never remove somebody else's event handler.  Compare to the accessor of a field, a property.  Which only permits get and set, it stops other code from writing the field value directly.